# configuring PHP-FPM service in CentOS 8 using Apache 2.4

Tags: php, centos, apache2.4

I have been trying to configure Php-FPM in CentOS 8 running on with Apache 2.4 and PHP version 7.2. I neeed to host multiple domains and I create a seperate pool for each domain by duplicating default `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to `domainname.conf` by changing the following parameters

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/domainname.com.sock
...
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = domainusername
listen.group = domainusername
listen.mode = 0660
user = domainsername
group = domainusername
```

I have user's home directory permission as 700. having enabled `LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so` uder `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf` and `disabled prefork module` entries in Apache virtualhost file of each domain

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
ServerName domainname.com
ServerAlias www.domainname.com
DocumentRoot /home/domainusername/public_html

<Directory /home/domainusername/public_html>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/domainname.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/domainname.com-access_log common

   SuexecUserGroup domainusername domainusername

 # Proxy declaration
        <Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/domainname.com.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">
                # we must declare a parameter in here (doesn't matter which) or it'll not register the proxy ahead of time
                ProxySet disablereuse=off
                # Note: If you configure php-fpm to use the "ondemand" process manager, then use "ProxySet disablereuse=on"
        </Proxy>

        # Redirect to the proxy
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
                SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
        </FilesMatch>



</VirtualHost>
```

However facing the issue with service:

- 1. getting 403 forbidden error since home directory is having 700. with the same permission it worked for mod_ruid2
- 2. Getting service unavailable if change the

     ```
     listen.owner = domainusername
     listen.group = domainusername
     ```

I really dont know whether I have configured it in right way since I'm new to Php-FPM. It would be great If I am able to get the desired out using Php-FPM as that of mod_ruid2 provided.

I referred the following link but found no luck `https://www.stephenrlang.com/2018/02/centos-7-apache-2-4-with-php-fpm/`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried [`listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache`](https://ruleoftech.com/2013/using-php-fpm-with-apache-2-on-centos)? What were the results?

Comment: Are you using  `mod_fastcgi`?

Comment: @Martin I installed  mod_fcgid..If I change listen.owner = apache listen.group = apache. ..the site will run under apache permission rite?

Comment: Have you configured `mod_fastcgi`? If so, then you can change the listener owner and group to Apache, yes.

Comment: I need to run each domain under the user's privilege instead of apache..If I change user and group to apache I am able to start the php-fpm service. In case of I am installing wordpress in one of the domain the permission falls under apache insteaed of user. This case is eliminated in using mod_ruid2..I really dont know whether php-fpm will server the same purpose as that of mod_ruid2?